# Encode header value using WebClient.Headers.Add()

Tags: c#, encoding, http-headers

I am using HTTP headers to send a string which contains Unicode characters (such as `ñ`) to a custom http server.

When I add the string as a header:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Custom-Data", "señor");
```

It is interpreted by the server as:

```
se�or
```

Obviously I need to encode the value differently, but I am unsure what encoding to use.

***How should I encode this HTTP header to preserve extended/special characters?***

- *[porneL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410331/161052) to a related question is confusing.*
- *Unanswered, related: [C# WebClient non-english request header value encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14751072/161052)*

Comment: webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?

Comment: @Jordan That just adds another header saying "the body content is html." I need to encode the *value* of a custom header, not the body/content.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something trivial like base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jordan suggested, representing the string as base64 (with UTF8 encoding) worked well:

On the client side:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Custom-Data",
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("señor")));
```

And on the server:

```
string customData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(customHeader.Value));
```